# Eclipse Menu Item to Exec Shell Command to Console

Tags: eclipse

Is is possible to create a custom menu item within eclipse that will perform a given shell command? I'm not looking to do a "run/debug" type thing, I want to simple shell out and run a given command. I am NOT looking to create a plugin either.

Comment: Geez, I can't believe I missed this!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Right past Run/Debug, there is something called External Tools. It looks like a green play icon with a toolbox. You can set these up to run anything you like, and anything you add to favorites will appear in a drop down menu for easy execution in two clicks. This can be used to run batch scripts, so that may do the trick for you.

Here's a [link](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/gettingStarted/qs-97_standalone_ets.htm) to the Eclipse Helios page on external tools that may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

There are already plugins for this, such as [Wicked Shell](http://www.wickedshell.net)

Answer (score 1):

Or you should read this: http://douglasfils.blogspot.com/2007/07/terminal-shell-in-eclipse.html